# Designing a point system in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, achievements

I have a lot of existing data in my database already, and want to develop a points mechanism that computes a score for each user based on what actions they do.

I am implementing this functionality in a pluggable way, so that it is independent of the main logic, and relies on Spring events being sent around, once an entity gets modified.

The problem is what to do with the existing data. I do not want to start collecting points from now, but rather include all the data until now.

What is the most practical way to do this? Should I design my plugins in such a way as to provide for an index() method, which will force my system to fetch every single entity from the database, send an EntityDirtyEvent, to fire the points plugins, for each one, and then update it, to let points get saved next to each entity. That could result in a lot of overhead, right?

The simplest thing would be to create a complex stored procedure, and then make the index() call that stored procedure. That however, seems to me like a bad thing either. Since I will have to write the logic for computing the points in java anyway, why have it once again in SQL? Also, in general I am not a fan of splitting business logic into the different layers.

Has anyone done this before? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

First let's distinguish between the implementation strategy and business rules.

Since you already have the data, consider obtaining results directly from the data. This forms the data domain model. Design the data model to store all your data. Then, create a set of queries, views and stored procedures to access and update the data.

Once you have those views, use a data access library such as Spring JDBC Template to fetch this data and represent them into java objects (lists, maps, persons, point-tables etc).

What you have completed thus far does not change much, irrespective of what happens in the upper layers of the system. This is called Model.

Then, develop a rule base or logic implementation which determines, under what inputs, user actions, data conditions or for all other conditions, what data is needed.  In mathetical sense, this is like a matrix. In programming sense, this would be a set of logic statements. If this and this and this is true, then get this data, else get that data, etc. This encompasses the logic in your system. Hence it is called "Controller".

Do not move this logic into the queries/stored procedure/views.

Then finally develop a front-end or "console" for this. In the simplest case, develop a console input system, which takes a    ..  and displays a set of results. This is your "view" of the system.

You can eventually develop the view into a web application. The above command-line view can still be viable in the form of a Restful API server.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is one problem here to be considered: as I understand there's huge data in the Database so the idea to create only one mechanism to calculate the point system could not be the best approach.

In fact if you don't want to start collecting points but include all the data, you must process and calculate the information you have now. Yes, the first time you will run this can result an overhead, but as you said, you need this data calculated.

By other hand you may include another mechanism that attends changes in an entity and launches a different process capable of calculate the new pointing diffence that applies to this particular modification.

So, you can use one Service responsible of calculate the pointing system, one for a single entity and another, may be longer to finish, capable of calculate the global points. Even, if you don't need to be calculated in real-time you can create a scheduled job responsible of launch it.

Finally, I know it's not a good approach to split the business logic in two layers (Db + Java) but sometimes is a requirement do it, for example, if you need to reply quickly to a request that finally works with a lot of registries. I've found some cases that there's no other option than add business logic to the database (as a stored procedures, etc) to manage a lot of data and return the final result to the browser client (ex: calculation process in one specific time).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to accomplish "bootstrapping." The approach you choose should depend on how complicated the point calculations are. If stored procedures or plain update statements are the simplest solution, do that.

If the calculations are complicated, write a batch job that loads your existing data, probably orders it oldest first, and fires the events corresponding to that data as if they've just happened. The code which deals with an event should be exactly the same code that will deal with a future event, so you won't have to write any additional code other than the batch jobs themselves.

Since you're only going to run this thing once, go with the simplest solution, even if it is quick and dirty.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be heading in the right direction.   You know you want your "points" thing decoupled from the main application.  Since it is implied you are already using hibernate (by the tag!), you can tap into the hibernate event system (see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html) section 14.2).   Depending upon the size/complexity of your system, you can plugin your points calculations here (if it is not a large/complex system), or you can publish your own event to be picked up by whatever software is listening.

The point in either design approach is that neither knows or cares about your point calculations.   If you are, as I am guessing, trying to create a fairly general purpose plugin mechanism, then you publish your own events to that system from this tie-in point.   Then if you have no plug-ins on a given install/setup, then no one gets/processes the events.  If you have multiple plug-ins on another install/setup, then they each can decide what processing they need to do based upon the event received.  In the case of the "points plugin" it would calculate it's point value and store it.  No stored proc required....

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways. 
One is you already know that -  poll the database for for changed data. In that case you are hitting the database when there may not be change and it may slow down your process.

Second approach - Whenever change happens in database, the database will fire the event. That you can to using CDC (Change Data Capture). It will minimize the overhead.

You can look for more options in [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration/)